# Regarding Degrees of Freedom and dynamics of polyatomic molecules

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, degrees-of-freedom, molecular-dynamics

Justify how a molecule with N atoms have $3N-5$ vibrational degrees of freedom(Linear) and $3N-6$ vibrational degrees of freedom (Non-linear). Will this be valid for large number of N?

Taking $H_2O$ as an example, please explicitly mention all the vibrational degrees of freedom, if possible pictorially.

If we treat a polyatomic molecule with N atoms as a collection of N independent monoatomic molecules, then the total degrees of freedom is $3N$. Is it justified to say that all the degrees of freedom combined for that polyatomic molecule is $3N$? If so, Why?.

Lastly,if possible give me a deeper explanation regarding the intrinsic Dynamics of molecules, mathematical explanation based on Newtonian mechanics is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it justified to say that all the degrees of freedom combined for that polyatomic molecule is $3N$ ?

Yes, that is correct.

$3$ degrees of freedom correspond to translational movements of the molecule as a whole, so that leaves $3N-3$ degrees of freedom for rotations of the molecule as a whole and vibrations.

For a non-linear molecule there are $3$ degrees of freedom that correspond to rotations about any set of three mutually perpendicular axes. So that leaves $3N-6$ degrees of freedom for vibrations.

For a linear molecule there are only $2$ degrees of freedom that correspond to rotations because a rotation about an axis along the line of the atoms does not change the configuration of the atoms (equivalently we can say that the line of the atoms points to a point on the surface of a sphere, which has $2$ dimensions). So that leaves $3N-5$ degrees of freedom for vibrations.

These formulae are valid for any value of $N$ greater than $1$, as long as the molecule is free to vibrate in any mode. A molecule that is constrained in some way (because of van der Waals forces, for example) may have fewer degrees of freedom.

Obviously the formulae for vibrational degrees of freedom do not hold for $N=1$, and a "molecule" that consists of a single atom has only $3$ degrees of freedom that correspond to translations. And  you can argue that $N=2$ is also a special case because a diatomic molecule must be linear, so it has $3$ translational degrees of freedom, $2$ rotational degrees of freedom, and just $1$ vibrational degree of freedom - the only possible vibrational mode is for the atoms to move towards and away from one another.

I'll leave you to picture what the $3$ vibrational degrees of freedom look like for a water molecule (which is no-linear).

Comment: In order to find the degrees of freedom for any specific molecule, one must take into account the individual structure of the molecule, as different types of chemical bonds have different intrinsic symmetries that limit the degrees of freedom. For example orbital hybridizations, electron delocalization as in $\pi$ bonds, etc.

Comment: Could you justify why the combined degrees of freedom is 3N? It seems extremely handwavy.

Comment: @AdityaKrishnaPanickar $N$ atoms times $3$ spatial dimensions = $3N$ total degrees of freedom. In other words, we need $3$ independent co-ordinates to define the position of each of the $N$ atoms, giving $3N$ degrees of freedom altogether.

Comment: So, combination/coupling of two or more of these translational motion gives rise to more "exotic" rotational and vibrational modes.  Could you relate it with coupling of differential equations by any chance?